# How to differenciate thoughts?

Tags: waswasa

So a person goes through waswaas quite a lot. Alhamdulilah, they felt like it is reducing now. But still thoughts about Allah (SWT) comes. The person is not sure now, if the thought is from themselves or shaytaan. So how do you DIFFERENTIATE thoughts?

Comment: Don't you realize that most of your questions are only new versions from former questions of your own. Please take your time and ask a well elaborated question instead of creating question duplicates!

Comment: But some of them don't recieve answers, that's why, there are duplicates.

Comment: If a question is not answered that means either none of us has enough knowledge or time to answer it or it has issues which usually are addressed in comments. Duplicate posts are disliked on stackexchange network.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what I write will be fully on-topic but just wanted to help.

There's no way to differentiate these unless one displays the severe symptoms associated with an all-out demonic possession which is obviously not your case.

But to combat these thoughts, you don't have to try chasing them out of your mind or feeling guilt or getting overly stressed. These reactions are completely counterproductive. Instead you distract yourself by engaging in productive work, socializing, physical exercise, praying in congregation, doing the housework, taking a bath, etc. Choose those hobbies in particular that are less stressful and cause less mental burden. You want to do them with convenience, enjoy and relax.

If these don't work, you will then certainly need to consult a physician. There could be problems with your diet, life habits, or your overall psychological health. Only a specialist can tell.

*wa huwa yashfin*...