# Is this kufr and blasphemous?

Tags: kufr, blasphemy

Selam. I need you to reply this question as if it doesn't contain a single mistake or unclarity in its description. If someone makes the intention of imagining the sentence < The almighty has a child> and he imagines that sentence as if he is seeing it in a book or letter. He imagines that sentence word by word. He doesn't imagine sounds or voices. He simply imagines that sentence. Level of sin? The only intention he has is imagining that sentence. < Yzeir is the son of God>  Idols are intermediatery to God >  In other words imagining those blasphemous sayings in the manner I described above.

Comment: On what bases have you have decided that my question deserves -2.  You behave as if i have a big fault and sin for not being able to understand this thing. You behave as if i have a big fault and sin for having an illness called OCD that was given to me without my choice. Often good people like prophet's have suffered from illnesses and calamities. I am not saying, i am a prophet, but compare my sins that i haven't harmed anybody with the sins of those that kill women and children on a daily basis. And yet they are the most respected to the point that Muslims carve carpets for their welcoming.

Comment: Not much to worry about if they are really compulsive. But you have to try reduce them by seeking remedies. I have written an extensive answer to a similar condition that you may find helpful https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/56153/4058

Comment: Also https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/56116/4058

Comment: But if you don't have OCD and do it exactly as I described. Is it kufr?   Please reply yes or no.

Comment: No, if you don't believe in what your mind compels you to think, it is not kufr because you don't have the intention. This is what is suggested by http://tanzil.net/#16:106 too. But you surely have an obligation to seek treatment.

Comment: And as for the opposite of this, i.e. not having OCD and imagining the sentences: the question would be of intentions: why would one want to imagine blasphemous statements? But ultimately if you are imagining those statements without confirming them with your heart, it is not kufr but again they can either be a laqw (useless) thing or a step towards kufr. So only if there's a necessary purpose behind them, they will be legit but I can't think of a necessary purpose for imagining them unless you're reading/reviewing material by an atheist or a theological dispute for learning purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Wa alaikumu As-Salamu wa Rahmatullahi wa Barakatuh.

**What matters is your heart; as long as you don't believe in it, in shaa Allah it's fine.**

I advice you to avoid such thoughts and make Dhikr (**Subhanallah** (Pure and Perfect is Allah, for He has no error whatsoever), **Al-Hamdulilah** (All praise is due to Allah, for all the blessings, such as the sight, the hearing and the mind, that He has given us), **Allahu Akbar** (Allah is the Greatest, and there's no one that can challenge Him in power, if all mankind and Jinn were to commit Kufr as much as the most mischievous of His slaves, that would ***not*** harm Him, and if all mankind and Jinn were to have Iman like that of the most righteous one of His slaves, that would ***not*** raise Him higher), and others)

Also read more Qur'an and make more voluntary deeds, for these in shaa Allah help strengthen your Iman, and remember:

[image: إِنَّ اللَّهَ مَعَ الصَّابِرِينَ]

> Indeed, Allah is with the patient
>
> [Surah Al-Baqarah 2:153](https://quran.com/2/153?translations=)

Brother if you have any question you may ask, may Allah reward you with good

Answer (score 0):

Assalamoalikum.

Brother, thoughts, and acknowledging them are two similar yet different things.

**Let me elaborate,**

A thought is what comes to the mind, in this case, the possible "Allah has a son" (Ma'adAllah), **THIS** is a thought, thoughts **may be generated by Shaitan**. This is something **that came** to your mind with or without reason, **BUT**, **YOU** didn't acknowledge and agree to it. When you **ACKNOWLEDGE** and **BELIEVE** this thought that just came to your mind, that is when you commit **Shirk**.

The human mind can with or without reason get any sort of thoughts, but **getting thoughts and believing them** are two different things. In Islam, **having** bad thoughts is not a sin as it is **human nature** to get random thoughts, **BUT IF YOU BELIEVE ON THAT EVIL THOUGHT, It is then when you are sinful**.

**In this case**

You did not acknowledge/admit/believe that Allah has a son, this thought came to your mind from Shaitan, simply ignore it and keep fearing Allah and seek Allah's refuge from such evil thoughts.

I don't know how to type Arabic but check **Qur'an chapter 23 verse no. 97-98**.

> **"My Lord! I seek refuge with You from the whisperings of the Shayatin (devils). And I seek refuge with You, My Lord! lest they should come near me."  (Surah Al Mominun, Chapter 23, verse no. 97-98)**

As brother, **Qataada**, mentioned in his answer, **"what matters is your heart"**. Do you acknowledge and believe on such evil thoughts? If no, then you are not sinful.

**And Allah knows the best.**